# Azure AD No User Authentication in Spring Boot

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, bearer-token, jwt

I want to login to my application with the use of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token` endpoint. I'm filling parameters(client_id, client_secret, resource and grant_type:client_credentials) in post request and getting access token. When I use it to login my API spring boot gives me error:

```
com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: {"error_description":"AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in.
```

What should I do to get valid bearer token with only post request ? Or is there any azure configuration I am missing to ?

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? What version of Spring Boot are you using? How did you configure Spring Security?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Right now I'm using azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter 2.2.0.M1.
AADAuthenticationFilter filter added.
It is working with microsoft's pop-up but I need to get bearer without any GET request. I want to do it with POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe as 'login' is not a user login but an application request for an access token. The application can then use this token to call some other API, e.g. MS Graph. It is intended for use by applications where either there is no user involved at all (e.g. a daemon service) or the application wants to call an APIs without reference to the currently logged in user. If, what you want to do is to have a user signin to your application, you will need to use the OpenIDConnect Authorization Code Grant flow. Use [MSAL4J](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java).

Comment: All I want to do is getting access to my own spring-boot api all non-interactively. I don't want to get and pop-up or redirection. Can you give me some more information on this ?

Comment: You cannot do it without redirection unless you use the OAuth2 Resource Owner flow, which you shouldn't except in some edge cases. Its insecure, does not support MFA or SSO properly. All modern user-facing apps have to use redirection and separate popup UI to authn users.